# Catch Error from external API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, twilio

I am building a simple web app that sends SMS messages to cell phones using Twilio. I want to ensure that the user has entered a full 10 digit phone number before it will allow a message to attempt to be sent.

When I test it with a less-than or greater-than 10 digit number, in `heroku logs`, I see `Twilio::REST::RequestError (The 'To' number 1234567890 is not a valid phone number.)`.

I have tried to use a `begin`/`rescue` wrapper and am telling it to `render text: "Try again with a valid number."` and tried a variety of `if` statements to try to avoid the error.

I am pretty new to Ruby and Rails and Twilio, but I promise i have been through every guide I have found. Any help is greatly appreciated. Full code of my `UserController` below:

```
    require 'twilio-ruby'
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])

      account_sid = '...'
      auth_token = '...'

      if @user.save
         render text: "Wasn't that fun? Hit the back button in your browser to give it another go!"
    begin
       client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
           client.account.sms.messages.create(
           from: '+16035093259',
           to: @user.phone,
           body: @user.message
           )
        rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError
           render text: "Try again with a valid number."        
        end
     else
       render :new
     end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd extract the SMS sending logic into a separate model/controller and use a background job to process the submitting. The UserController should only handle, well, user creation/modification.

Scaffolding:

```
$ rails g model sms_job user:references message:text phone submitted_at:datetime
$ rake db:migrate
```

Model:

```rb
class SmsJob < AR::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :message, :phone

  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :message, :phone, :user_id
  validates :phone,
      length: { min: 10 },
      format: { with: /\+?\d+/ }

  scope :unsubmitted, where(submitted_at: nil)

  TWILIO = {
    from_no:      '...',
    account_sid:  '...',
    auth_token:   '...'
  }

  # find a way to call this method separately from user request
  def self.process!
    unsubmitted.find_each do |job|
      begin
        client = Twilio::REST::Client.new TWILIO[:account_sid], TWILIO[:auth_token]
        client.account.sms.messages.create(
          from: TWILIO[:from_no],
          to:   job.phone,
          body: job.message
        )
        job.submitted_at = Time.zone.now
        job.save
      rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError
        # maybe set update a tries counter
        # or delete job record
        # or just ignore this error
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The controller then should just provide the information that the SMS is going to be send:

```
# don't forget the 'resources :sms_jobs' in your routes.rb
class SmsJobsController < ApplicationController
  # index, update, destroy only for only admin?

  def new
    @sms_job = SmsJobs.new
  end

  def create
    @sms_job = current_user.sms_jobs.build params[:sms_job]
    if @sms_job.save
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Your message is being send!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

For the background processing, have a look at these excellent [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32) :-) You probably need to workaround some concurrency problems if you have to process many messages and/or Twilio has a long response time (didn't use that service yet).

Comment: Wow, thank you. I am very new to Rails so a lot of this is over my head. If you would care to explain some of this to a beginner, that would be really awesome, otherwise thanks for all of this anyways and I will try to figure out how to incorporate this in. I still havent figured out the whole class structure, file system and what the routes.rb file is really about. You can see my current app at bsstexter.herokuapp.com. It only sends texts to my phone right now because of a trial Twilio account, but you can see what it lacks and you can still click through to see the heroku default error page.